# MYSQL Union All not returning all record by two merging query

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

```
SELECT tah.project_id_new as "project_id", tah.history_createdon from task_audit_history tah 
where task_id=64 and project_id != project_id_new;
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0thnx.png)

```
SELECT tah.project_id as "project_id", tah.history_createdon from task_audit_history tah 
where task_id=64 ORDER BY history_createdon asc limit 1;
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IB53.png)

```
When I tried to combined above two queries using UNION ALL it return only one record. Why ? i mean it 
should include all record from two query.

SELECT tah.project_id_new as "project_id", tah.history_createdon from task_audit_history tah 
where task_id=64 and project_id != project_id_new UNION ALL SELECT tah.project_id as "project_id", tah.history_createdon from task_audit_history tah 
where task_id=64 ORDER BY history_createdon asc limit 1;
```

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x6Xc.png)

Comment: Show precise SQL text for 3rd query.

Comment: Nex time please paste the results as text here instead of linking to images. Read here why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result implies that the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses are being applied to the entire union query, not just the subquery (which is the behavior you want).  Try using this version:

```sql
(SELECT tah.project_id_new AS project_id, tah.history_createdon
 FROM task_audit_history tah 
 WHERE task_id = 64 AND project_id != project_id_new)
UNION ALL
(SELECT tah.project_id AS project_id, tah.history_createdon
 FROM task_audit_history tah 
 WHERE task_id = 64
 ORDER BY history_createdon
 LIMIT 1);
```

For completeness, the following query is what you were likely originally running to end up with just a single row:

```sql
SELECT tah.project_id_new AS project_id, tah.history_createdon
FROM task_audit_history tah 
WHERE task_id = 64 AND project_id != project_id_new
UNION ALL
SELECT tah.project_id AS project_id, tah.history_createdon
FROM task_audit_history tah 
WHERE task_id = 64
ORDER BY history_createdon
LIMIT 1;
```

In this case, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause applies to the *entire* union query, which means it will return just a single record.